# Cannot set property 'className' of null at setThemeFromCookie

Tags: css, javascript, html, debug, body-class

I am coding in WordPress to make a button to toggle body class from `light-mode` to `dark-mode`. i was experimenting with trying to add a cookie so that the preference is remembered for the browser. But i receive a error `Cannot set property className of null at setThemeFromCookie`.

moreover clicking the button gives another error `(index):486 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null at togglePageContentLightDark`

My url is https://milyin.com
you can see the button in blue color located in footer

JS follows

```
 function togglePageContentLightDark() {
      var body = document.getElementById('body')
      var currentClass = body.className
      var newClass = body.className == 'dark-mode' ? 'light-mode' : 'dark-mode'
      body.className = newClass

  document.cookie = 'theme=' + (newClass == 'light-mode' ? 'light' : 'dark')
  console.log('Cookies are now: ' + document.cookie)
}

function isDarkThemeSelected() {
  return document.cookie.match(/theme=dark/i) != null
}

function setThemeFromCookie() {
  var body = document.getElementById('body')
  body.className = isDarkThemeSelected() ? 'dark-mode' : 'light-mode'
}

(function() {
  setThemeFromCookie()
})();
```

HTML for button

```
<button type="button" name="dark_light" onclick="togglePageContentLightDark()" title="Toggle dark/light mode"></button>
```

i am fairly new to Java script and this code was taken from internet only. Please help me debug this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using JQuery Simplifies the whole thing, using [JS Cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Check cookie and set theme
    if(Cookies.get('theme')) {

        $('body').removeClass('light-mode dark-mode').addClass( Cookies.get('theme') );

    };


    //Switch theme and create the cookie...

    $("#theme-toggler").click(function(){

         if ($('body').hasClass( 'light-mode')){
            $('body').removeClass('light-mode').addClass('dark-mode');
            Cookies.set('theme', 'dark-mode');

         }else  {
            $('body').removeClass('dark-mode').addClass('light-mode');
            Cookies.set('theme', 'light-mode');
         }

     });

});
```

Add `id` to `button`.

```
<button id="theme-toggler" type="button" name="dark_light"  title="Toggle dark/light mode"></button>
```

Also add this script

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: tried yours. the cookies work but class is not changing. it still doesn't toggle from light-mode to dark-mode.also note it that i manually added the body class via php, the script doesn't add the class forget about toggling it

Comment: Check the updated answer. Now at least toggle button should work!

Comment: BTW why not use jQuery?

Comment: well i don't have much experience of Jquery, didn't want to mess things up

Comment: Did copy paste your jQuery code in head, and added the html for button as it is. Didn't work, also added the innitial body class using php 'light-mode' but i am afraid no success, 

Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):126)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:1)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:1)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:1)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:1)

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal sorry, I forgot to add details. Check the new Jquery code in updated answer. It works here in my local setup.

Comment: Thanks let me test it. WIll get back to u soon

Comment: it worked but it created another trouble. Upon click it removes all classes other than ligh-mode/dark-mode. My body tag has 7-8 other classes added by wordpress and various plugins, is there anyway to preserve those classes

Comment: Check now the updated answer!

Comment: Did it work now?

Comment: No, and i am trying to debug but no luck.

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: No errors in console, the code is executed but the class light-mode is light-mode, there is no change even after repeated clicks, the class does not change. You can urself check my url https://milyin.com/

Comment: Required JS is missing on your site. Add it.

Comment: Hey, that is because of caching and Service Worker. I will clear cache

Comment: Hey would you mind sharing your email id, so that I can give you my site user id and password. The logged in users are served updated content, and you yourself can test the code there

Comment: Sent, gave you details about my login credentials and the place where my code is inserted so that you can analyse.

Answer (score 0):

`var body = document.getElementById('body')` is your problem.  The document's body is not an id, it's a tag.  Use `var body = document.querySelector('body');`

Comment: Actually `document.body` would be the fastest way to target the body element.

Comment: the toggle doesn't work. it still shows error in console